# Как заставить изображение выйти за пределы дива

Tags: html, css

Есть такой макет.

[image: Текст]

Как вы видите, изображение наполовину выходит за предел контейнера. Я уже больше часа бьюсь над этой задачей, но не могу достичь желаемого результата. Я уже пыталась и `img` засунуть в контейнер, а потом при помощи функции `left: calc();` его вывести, и расположить его вне контейнер - ничего не помогает. Посмотрите, пжста, мой код? Где я ступила? Либо я вообще не правильно реализовала идею?

```css
.giftset-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.giftset-box img {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(100% - 409/2);
}

.giftset-text {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 790px;
  padding: 90px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 2px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 2px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 2px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<section id="giftset" class="giftset">
  <div class="section-title">
    <p>Best Gift For Best Friend</p>
    <h2>GIFTSET</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="giftset-box">
    <img src="img/pr-0018-r.png" alt="gift">
    <div class="giftset-text">
      <p class="price">285.000</p>
      <h4>Giftset "Cà phê phin Việt Nam"</h4>
      <p class="card-ingridients">Món quà tuyệt vời dành cho người sành cà phê. Hạt cà phê được Revo cẩn trọng chọn lựa, rang xay theo công nghệ và bí quyết học hỏi từ những nghệ nhân nổi tiếng, cùng với tình yêu, sự đam mê của người làm cà phê… tạo ra những tách cà phê tinh khiết
        chỉ dành riêng cho bạn.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: position: absolute

Comment: Было бы не плохо, если бы было больше информации. Могу посоветовать вам посмотреть к чему привязано  relative, возможно именно из за него нет возможности увести блок, в крайнем случае можно воспользоваться  transform  и применить его, костыль конечно, но если по другому вот прям никак...

Comment: transform: tranlsateX(-60%);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы обернул картинку и относительно этой обёртки выдал картинке `position: absolute; right: 0;`, тогда картинка уже бы применила вид того, что на макете.

```css
.giftset-box {
  display: flex;
    max-width: 500px;
  margin: 70px auto 0;
    background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 2px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
}

.giftset-image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.giftset-image img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 300px; /* Т.к. картинка на absolute, то она будет тянуться на весь свой размер, по этому ограничим максимальным по макету */
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -35%; /* Примерный отступ тени снизу */
    object-fit: contain;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.giftset-text {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section id="giftset" class="giftset">
  <div class="section-title">
    <p>Best Gift For Best Friend</p>
    <h2>GIFTSET</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="giftset-box">
    <div class="giftset-image">
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/60rpeK9.png" alt="gift">
    </div>
    <div class="giftset-text">
      <p class="price">285.000</p>
      <h4>Giftset "Cà phê phin Việt Nam"</h4>
      <p class="card-ingridients">Món quà tuyệt vời dành cho người sành cà phê. Hạt cà phê được Revo cẩn trọng chọn lựa, rang xay theo công nghệ và bí quyết học hỏi từ những nghệ nhân nổi tiếng, cùng với tình yêu, sự đam mê của người làm cà phê… tạo ra những tách cà phê tinh khiết
        chỉ dành riêng cho bạn.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо большое) помогло